# Test if value is Decimal

Tags: python, decimal

In some Python (v3) code I am creating lists of [Decimals](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) from user input, like this:

```
input = [] # later populated with strings by user with values like '1.45984000E+001'
decimals = [Decimal(c) for c in input]
```

However, sometimes the input list contains strings that cannot be parsed. How can I test if c can be represented as a decimal before calling the constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't. Catch the exception thrown by the constructor. If that means turning the list comprehension into a for loop then so be it.

Comment: Isn't exception throwing costly?

Comment: @fatcat1111, Not really, Python is not C++ or Java. Besides this is the *only* reasonable way to solve your particular problem

Answer (score 3):

#### Catch exception

```
decimals = []
for s in input:
    try: decimals.append(Decimal(s))
    except InvalidOperation:
        pass
```

#### Use helper function

```
from itertools import imap

def parse_decimal(s):
    try: return Decimal(s)
    except InvalidOperation:
        return None

decimals = [d for d in imap(parse_decimal, input) if d is not None]
```